# Flot chart unwanted decimals on changing width

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, charts, flot

I am using google flot chart which displays graph on the base of the values selected by the user. Graph displays years on x-axis and prices on y-axis.

The problem is that if graph width is small it displays values properly. for example if I set width as

```
<div id="placeholder" style="width:500px;height:300px"></div>
```

But if the graph width is increased just like

```
<div id="placeholder" style="width:650px;height:300px"></div>
```

Graph show unwanted zeroes on x-axis 
e.g

```
Insted of  2010  it shows  2010.0
Insted of  2011  it shows  2011.0
Insted of  2012  it shows  2012.0
```

I just want to get rid of these unwanted zeroes. Google didn't help me at all and I've totally no idea for this stupid behavior of flot.

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem too. I could easily fix it like this:

```
xaxis:
{                
    tickDecimals: 0
}
```

Comment: I've had this work when removing all decimals, but when I just want 1, 2, 3, etc., I've had it choke on floats (ie `3.12000000000001` when I ask for two decimals). Better to use `tickFormatter` and your own rounding function in those situations.

Answer (score 2):

Looking through [the doco](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/API.txt), you might want to try setting `tickDecimals` or setup a `tickFormatter` for the `xaxis` option.

Comment: I guess this is what you are talking about

`tickFormatter: (fn: number, object -> string) or string`
`tickDecimals: null or number`

So how should i set them up making sure that 
As in database I have values based on quarters of year so if i want to show a graph of only 2001 it may show on X-Axis

`2001    2001.25     2001.5     2001.75`

if i want to show a graph of only 2001 and 2002 the on X-Axis it may show like

`2001   2001.5     2002    2002.5`

and if i want to show a graph of 2001, 2002, 2003 and 2004 then on X-Axis

`2001    2002     2003    2004`

Comment: the tickformatter gets passed the axis object. From there you could check the max and min. If the max and min are the same, do the quarters. If they're 1 year apart, do the halves. Etc. Or, if you know ahead of time that you're showing quarters, halves or wholes, setup the axis with some manual ticks - you an specify `ticks: [2001,2002,etc]`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 0.7 or the master branch from Github?  This sounds like a bug that was recently fixed on the master branch.